# “Is he pushing lung cancer on/to his viewers?” Any difference between "on" and "to"?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

By looking up dictionaries, push means sell.

But I am not sure what is the difference between

> he is pushing lung cancer on his viewers

and

> he is pushing lung cancer to his viewers

I read this on imgur.

> Is he… **pushing** lung cancer **on** his viewers?
> I'm not even trying to be snarky.
> What the actual f*ck?
>
> Acyn @Acyn • 16h
> Tucker “They hate nicotine. They love THC.. Why do they hate nicotine?
> Because nicotine frees your mind and the thc makes you compliant and passive”

[image: screenshot of Tucker Carlson on Fox News]

Comment: Push can mean more things than 'sell', e.g. 'encourage'. The Carlson creature is encouraging his viewers to smoke and, perhaps, get lung cancer (or a number of other diseases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "*Push*" in this sort of context can mean any of "Sell", "Persuade to use" "advocate for" or "force on someone". Other senses are also possible. In this case, I read the meaning as closer to "advocate for", although it could also be taken as "force on others".

Comment: Any difference between **he is pushing lung cancer on his viewers** and ***he is pushing lung cancer to his viewers***?

Comment: @Stats Cruncher In this context I don't see any significant difference. In general "*push to*" might be used more for the "sell" or persuade" sense, and "*push on*" more for the "force" or "impose" sense, but a given use might not stick to that distinction.